# How to write xlsx document with nodejs

Tags: node.js, xlsx

Basically i need write a **spreadsheet** document in **Nodejs** with images and formatted text. I found some libraries to write xlsx files but they have bugs and the new document can't be opened neither libreoffice or google drive and Ms Excel do some strange things before open the file.

I tried with:

- xlsx
- msexcel-builder
- msexcel-builder-colorfix
- msexcel-builder-extended
- Others...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please let us know what you have tried so that we can help you out?

Comment: I tried with https://www.npmjs.com/package/msexcel-builder, the file was generated, but with some errors, in other libraries is not possible write the text with a nice format. So, can anyone recommend another library.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xls 
try this package, if you find any difficulty then please share you code.